# Bundle.js missing from the list

Tags: angular

This is the first time I want to deploy a test app. So I ran a `ng build --prod`
My tutorial says there should be a main.bundle.js file too.
But I can see some main.js files in there but no .bundle.js

Am I doing it wrong?

[image]

Comment: That's right. Angular CLI is evolving and now it generates two main bundles

Comment: Thank you. Yes it worked. I was able to deploy it. Book was using something called "now" .. was pretty use to use.